# Creating Inner Classes and using them (understanding some code)

Tags: java

I have been reading through some documentation on inner classes, and am currently reading my textbook, where I have found some good knowledge on using Inner classes. For starters I would like to consider the following example and just make sure I am understand things correctly. For reference I have read the follwing [Inner Classes Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) and have read a couple of SO questions. Hopefully someone can guide me through the following.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Gearbox {
    private ArrayList<Gear> gears;
    private int maxGears;
    private int currentGear;

    public Gearbox(int maxGears)
    {
        this.maxGears = maxGears;
        this.gears = new ArrayList<Gear>();
        Gear neutral = new Gear(0,0.0);
        this.gears.add(neutral);
    }

    public class Gear
    {
        private int gearNumber;
        private double ratio;

        public Gear(int gearNumber,double ratio)
        {
            this.gearNumber = gearNumber;
            this.ratio = ratio;
        }

        public double driveSpeed(int revs){
            return revs * ratio;
        }
    }
}
```

In the `main.java`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       Gearbox ford = new Gearbox(6);
        Gearbox.Gear first = ford.new Gear(1,20);
        System.out.println(first.driveSpeed(10));
    }
}
```

What I am kind of confused about is the notation to actually use some stuff from the nested class. For example

```
 Gearbox ford = new Gearbox(6);
```

Here we make a `ford` object belonging to the class of `Gearbox`, which passes in a value of `6` to `maxGears`.

Next we have `Gearbox.Gear first = ford.new Gear(1,20);`, Here is where I am kind of confused on what is really going on. Does the `.Gear` let the compiler know that `Gear` is an inner class within `Gearbox`? If so, why is the next statement `ford.new Gear(1,12.3)`?

Wouldn't something like `Gearbox.Gear first = new ford.Gear(1,12.3);` make more sense?

Comment: Because `new ford.Gear` could also refer to a different class `Gear` in the `ford` package. `ford.new Gear` is a different syntactical construct that eliminates such ambiguity. Other than that, you'd have to ask the language designers: *Why?*.

Comment: That this syntax is pretty ugly is a very strong indication of a design flaw (in how you structure your code). If you need to have external code instantiate inner class instances, make a factory method on `Gearbox`, something like `ford.makeGear(1,20)`. But ideally, these inner class instances don't leak out at all.

Comment: In your case, it seems like `Gear` could be `static` at least. Then you can do `new Gearbox.Gear`. But why not make it a top-level class?

Comment: The book first showed this, and then on the next several pages makes the inner class private, and then static, just showing differences. I agree the example is kind of horrible, in the sense that gears and cars is just an odd example, thanks for the comments though guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Next we have
>
> ```
> Gearbox.Gear first = ford.new Gear(1,20);
> ```
>
> Here is where I am kind of confused on what is really going on. Does the .Gear let the compiler know that Gear is an inner class within Gearbox?

Yes ... sort of.  Actually, it is saying "I am talking about the `Gear` class that is declared in `Gearbox`.  It is not necessarily an inner class: it could be a nested class.

> If so, why is the next statement `ford.new Gear(1,12.3)` ?

An instance of an inner class must be created in the context of an instance of its enclosing outer class.  The `ford.new Gear(...)` is saying create the new `Gear` instance in the context of the `Gearbox` instance that `ford` refers to.

(If that still doesn't make sense, reread the above paying special attention to usage of the the word "instance".  An instance of a class is an object .....)

---

As @Thilo points out, making `Gear` an inner class (rather than a nested class) here does not really achieve anything.  It would probably be better to a redeclare `Gear` as

```
    public static class Gear ...
```

and then you would not need to qualify the `new` with an instance of the `Gearbox` class.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess everything seems a little fuzzy at first and clears over time lol!

Comment: Except for beards :-)  (And bears ... they will kill you :-) )

Comment: Haha yes. By the way Stephen are there any resources or books which explain how the compiler or the computer uses java behind the scenes how everything works. My book covers some basic things but I want to know how the compiler and other processes interact. I know SO isn't a website for book recs, but I don't know really how to look for such a book

Comment: How to look for a book?  Search Amazon!

Comment: What do I search though? There are millions of books, I am interested in one that talks about the compiler, all the books that I search are just guides on how to program in java, which tend (from the couple that ive skimmed) not really talk about how the code is run

Comment: Well the problem is that there are no books written that cover that sort of thing these days.  There simply are not enough people prepared to buy them to cover the cost of writing / editing / printing them.  You are better off looking for research papers, reading Java technical notes .... and reading the Java source code.

Comment: I see. Thanks, I just really hate not knowing whats going on when I click run, its bothering me.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner class is not static, which means it belongs to a concrete instance.

```
Gearbox.Gear first = new ford.Gear(1,12.3);
```

Means that you create a Gear for instance `ford`.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) you can read some more about inner class and about difference of static and non-static inner classes.

Comment: Looking at the (current implementation of) `Gear`, it could be made `static`.

Comment: What does concrete instance mean?

Comment: If your inner class is not `static`, it depends on an "outer" instance. You can only create a `Gear` if you attach it to a concrete instance of `Gearbox`. That why the call to `new` has to involve `ford`.

Comment: So this inner class is called non static inner class, correct?

Comment: No ... a "non static inner class" is correctly called a nested class.

Comment: `Gearbox ford = new Gearbox(6);` this is a creation of instance. Concrete instance means that if you instantiates for example `ford`, `audi` and `mercedes` of Gearbox, each of them are a concrete instance of class Gearbox. So you could create Gear for each of them and every Gear would have an implicit link to it's parent.

Comment: But, as @Thilo said, your class can simply make static. You don't need parent's class instance context in it.